# javascript sort strings based on numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array like this:

```
var myArray = [
  ['red', 350],
  ['yellow', 20],
  ['green', 75],
  ['blue', 100]
];
```

In the order of the numbers.
So the output should be:

```
var myArray = [
  ['red', 350],
  ['blue', 100],
  ['green', 75],
  ['yellow', 20]
];
```

I tried using .sort but I couldn't get it to work right.
Thanks!

Comment: `myArray.sort( ([,a],[,b]) => b - a )`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array by a date property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-array-by-a-date-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a custom sort function:

```
myArray.sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1]);
```